# Why can i cast a shadow on a plane with Three.js?

Tags: three.js

[this is the demo capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUWp1.png)

I am a new on Three.js and practice on light and shadow, i add some component in the scene but i can't see the shadow on the plane.I also try to replace the PlaneGeometry to BoxGeometry but still failed.Please help me on this issue, below is the code. Thanks lot!

```
    import { OrbitControls } from '../../examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
    import * as THREE from 'three'
    import Stats from '../../examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js'

    let scene, renderer, camera, cube
    let cameraControl
    let pointLight, ambientLight, spotLight
    let sphereLightMesh
    let rotateAngle = 0
    let pointLightHelper, cameraHelper

    function main() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene() // build scene
        
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
        renderer.shadowMap.enable = true
        renderer.shadowMap.type = 2

        // build camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
        camera.position.set(30, 30, 30)
        camera.lookAt(scene.position)

        // build orbitcontrol
        cameraControl = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
        cameraControl.enableDamping = true
        cameraControl.dampingFactor = 0.25

        // build cube
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6, 6, 6)
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff })
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        cube.position.set(0, 0, 0)
        cube.castShadow = true
        scene.add(cube)

        // build plane
        const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 60)
        const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
        let plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial)
        plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI
        plane.position.set(0, -7, 0)
        plane.receiveShadow = true
        scene.add(plane)

        ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040)
        scene.add(ambientLight)

        // build point light
        pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xccffcc, 1, 100)
        scene.add(pointLight)

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
    }

    function render() {
        cameraControl.update()
        requestAnimationFrame(render)
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }

    main()
    render()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to address:

- The attribute to enable the [shadow map](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.shadowMap) is `enabled` (not `enable`), e.g.:

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
```

- The [`castShadow`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.castShadow) attribute of the [`PointLight`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/PointLight) instance also needs to be set to true, e.g.:

```
pointLight.castShadow = true
```

Once these have been done, shadows are being cast, but you'll need to move the light out of the cube to see the result, e.g:

```
pointLight.position.set(0, 7, 0)
```

I found [this code example](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/shadows/PointLightShadow) from the three.js docs useful for troubleshooting this ✌

Comment: Nice! The key point is the "enabled"  and pointLight shadow attribute，it works fine. Thanks lot!!!!!